In Django `import-export` lib how to pass row if values in few rows don't meet specific conditions?
I have a few dynamic fields (2) in ModelResource class.
I need to export a row only if at least one of those fields has a value:
+----+-------+-------+
| ID | col A | col B |
+====+=======+=======+
| 1  |       | value | # <-- exports
+----+-------+-------+
| 2  | value |       | # <-- exports
+----+-------+-------+
| 3  |       |       | # <-- passes as no values in both columns
+----+-------+-------+

Is there a way to achive this goal in import-export lib or I have to edit a tablib dataset ?
P.S. Data exports to Excel if that matters.

you can override a hook like after_export().  You will have to add logic to manipulate the tablib dataset directly and remove rows which don't match your rules.
